# What is the right way to have a set of structs in c++?

Tags: c++, set, std

I need to have a set of custom structs in order to be able to quickly retrive the instance with the smallest given parameter. However, I discovered that std::set considers some instances the same, even though they have different values. Here is my example program:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int foo, bar;
    S(int foo, int bar): foo(foo), bar(bar) {}
};

inline bool operator<(const S& a, const S& b)
{
    return a.foo < b.foo;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<S> baz;
    baz.emplace(1, 2);
    baz.emplace(1, 3);
    std::cout << baz.size();

    return 0;
}
```

This program prints **1**

std::set considers `S(1, 2)` and `S(1, 3)` to be the same. I'm guessing this is because `bar` is not used when comparing them. But I need the set to keep both elements, how do I solve this?

EDIT: I feel I have not stated my question correctly: I want to keep instances that are not exactly the same, but `std::multiset` does not work for me, because I don't want identical instances to be in the container

SOLUTION: I think I understand what was wrong. I assumed that if for 2 elements `a < b` and `b < a` were both true, it would result in undefined behaviour. But std::set checks for this, so it removes one of the elements. The best solution for me is to modify the comparator so it includes `bar`.

Comment: I know that in our company, I saw `memcmp` used for this purpose. But I don't know if it's the "right" way.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `memcmp` .... eh, better not. What about padding bytes?

Comment: Could you please expand on what exactly is your question? You pretty much answered it yourself. The `S` instances are considered equivalent because `bar` is not considered in the comparison and `std::set` doesn't keep equivalent elements. What exactly do you need answered? Your comments on answers so far seem to indicate that you have some additional reasons not to include `bar` in the comparison or to use `std::multiset` instead. Please explain those in the question.

Comment: @DanielJour I just said that I saw that in existing code. If I remember correctly: it was mostly done for POD structs. So I _guess_ padding is not that big of an issue.. Mostly..

Comment: @Yur3k Please define precisely what you mean with "*not exactly the same*". Are you maybe using `operator<` for something else than the `std::set` and that is the reason you don't want to modify it?

Comment: @walnut "not exactly the same" means they have at least one differing parameter

Comment: @Yur3k if two instances are not equivalent, one of them must be greater than the other. How do we decide which one is greater?

Comment: @Yur3k ok, then modifying `operator<` to include `bar` as suggested by some answers works for your purposes?

Comment: @Axyan It doesn't really matter in this situation. Are you saying that unless std::set gets different answers for `a < b` and `b < a` it won't guess which one is greater?

Comment: @Yur3k If `a < b` and `b < a` are false, `a` and `b` will be considered equivalent. If only one is true, then the order implied by the true one is taken. Both are not allowed to be true. That would cause undefined behavior in `std::set`.

Comment: @Yur3k that is correct. It does not take any guesses.

Comment: It's not up to `std::set` to **guess** when you explicitly **told** it how to compare two `S` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying a bit, `std::set` compares two elements twice when inserting:

1. `a < b`
2. `b < a`

If 1. is `true`, then `a` goes before `b` in ordering.
Else if 2. is `true`, then `b` goes before `a`.
Else (both are `false`), `a` and `b` are equivalent.

Since `S{1, 2} < S{1, 3} == false` and `S{1, 3} < S{1, 2} == false` according to your definition of `operator <`, they are deemed equivalent and `std::set::emplace` fails.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you only compare `foo`, and if `foo` is equivalent, the objects are considered equivalent. `std::set` keeps only one of equivalent values. If `bar` makes objects unique, include `bar` in the comparison or else, if you still want to keep both (equivalent) values, use a `std::multiset`. Both are valid solutions depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Those 2 solutions obviously work, but I don't need to use `bar` in the comparison, and if I just put `bar` in there the compiler might optimize it out.

Comment: @Yur3k do you want to compare `bar` or not? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @Axyxan `bar` doesn't matter in this situation

Comment: What behavior would you like? Why is `multiset` not the solution you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

It's not `std::set` that considers instances of `S` the same if they have the same `foo`, it's your own `operator<`.

So you either have to:

- change your `operator<` (which would also affect sorts), or
- use a different [comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) for your set (the second type parameter), or
- change your `operator<` to be fit for `std::set` and use a different `Compare` parameter for `std::sort` (or however you get the smallest element).

Bottom line, if you want a different compare functionality for `std::sort` (or whatever) and `std::set`, you need to *provide* different functionality.

As you did not really specify *why* your `operator<` looks the way it does (not considering `S::bar`), it's hard to tell what would match your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

If both `foo` and `bar` make `S` unique, then you can modify your `operator<` to use both variables, like so:

```
inline bool operator<(const S& a, const S& b)
{
    if ( a.foo == b.foo )
       return a.bar < b.bar;
    return a.foo < b.foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps as addition to the other answers:

`std::set` keeps a *sorted* set, and uses the `<`-relation created by the `operator<` to sort the elements.

So given two objects `a` and `b` ... if `! (a < b)` **and** `! (b < a)`, then neither is `a` "less" than `b`, nor is `b` "less" than `a`. Therefore `a == b` - from the perspective of the sorted order however.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `std::multiset` 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/